# Index table not displayed on new element type

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a data tables plugin and am currently working on the index page in the CP.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/element-types.html#index-page):

index.twig

```
{% extends '_layouts/elementindex' %}
{% set title = "DataTables"|t('app')  %}
{% set elementType = 'matfish\\DataTables\\elements\\DataTable' %}

{% block actionButton %}
 <div id="extra-headers">
    <div class="buttons right">
      <a href="{{ url('datatables/tables/new') }}" class="btn submit add icon">
       {{ "New DataTable"|t('datatables')}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Page is rendered but the table area is empty:
[image]

Table Attributes are defined on element class, and are displayed in dropdown:

```php
 protected static function defineTableAttributes(): array
    {
        return [
            'title' => \Craft::t('app', 'Title'),
            'elementType' => \Craft::t('datatables', 'Element Type'),
            'fields' => \Craft::t('datatables', 'Fields'),
        ];
    }
```

[image]

When I compared to other index pages I noticed that the ajax calls that are used to get the data and render the table are not fired:

```
index.php?p=admin/actions/element-indexes/get-elements&v=163847
index.php?p=admin/actions/element-indexes/count-elements&v=1638471423198
```

There are no JS errors in the console.

---

Edit 19-11-2022: Plugin ready at https://plugins.craftcms.com/tablecloth?craft4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sources at the left side of your element index picture.

i think you missed [source definition](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/element-types.html#sources) at your element type class:

it can be something simple like:

```
protected static function defineSources(string $context = null): array
{
    return [
        [
            'key' => '*',
            'label' => 'All Items',
            'criteria' => []
        ],
    ];
}
```

those requests are not fired because there is no criteria to pass via request without defining sources.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing I forgot was defining the query class on the `find` method. (https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/element-types.html#element-query-class). Without it Craft will just load all elements in the system.